# Ethernet video input to RCA composite output

Tags: raspbian, usb, composite-video

I have a model B raspberry pi running raspbian with an 8GB sd card. I want to connect my laptop by ethernet cable to my RPi and then output the laptops screen over the RCA composite output of the RPi to my analogue TV.

Laptop >> ethernet cable >> RPi >> RCA composite >> TV

I am aware of vnc options but the framerate using vnc is too slow when displaying video. I want something faster.

What software do I need on the laptop and on the RPi?

Comment: What OS is on the laptop?

Comment: consider using ethernet instead of the usb part, makes things a lot easier :)

Comment: @Wilf The laptop is Windows 7

Comment: @Gotschi I can use an ethernet cable instead of teh usb cable. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get best results in using something like [Airparrot](http://www.airsquirrels.com/airparrot/) in combination with [rplay](http://www.vmlite.com/index.php?option=com_kunena&func=view&catid=23&id=10991)

This solution uses Apples Display Mirroring feature and delivers (in my opinion) the best experience (smooth & easy to set up for beginners, a license key for the beta can be obtained in [their forums](http://www.vmlite.com/index.php?option=com_kunena&Itemid=158&func=showcat&catid=23) for free)

The second possible way would be to just Install a VNC Server on the Win7 Machine and start a client on the Pi (ssvnc for example)

The VNC solution is probably quite laggy, but still pretty easy to setup.

A third option would be to capture the desktop on the pc with VLC and play the stream with the pi

Comment: I have tried with VNC on the laptop and tightVNC on the RPi but found the framerate too slow to watch videos. I will try Airparrot and rplay shortly.

Comment: Airparrot with rplay works very well with video. The framerate is high and has no buffering. The audio does not work. When I enable audio on Airparrot it says "Connecting..." but never connects. I have changed the preferences without success. Does anyone know how to transfer audio on Airparrot to Raspberry Pi?